# why this still execute even set to nullptr

Tags: c++

I set the pointer to class to nullptr but when I access member function is still works

```
class A{
public :
    void f1(){std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;};
    virtual void f2(){std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {

    A* a = nullptr;
    a->f1();
    a->f2();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling methods via a `null` pointer is **undefined behavior**.  However, your methods don't access any class data members, so the value of the `this` pointer inside the methods is irrelevant. Make the methods access a class member, particularly a dynamically allocated one like a `std::string` or `std::vector`, and then they will be more likely to crash the way you are expecting.

Comment: Welcome to Undefined Behaviour. One of the worst outcome - program seem to be working and produce expected result.

Comment: lol now can I ask how do you know all this cool things :)

Comment: @Dilnar programming by guessing does not work, especially on C++ - you need to know what you are doing. Calling method on `nullptr` is UB according to the language standard.

Comment: @Dilnar You read [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).